# I am trying to figure out how to delete and entry by value from a singly linked-list

Tags: javascript, singly-linked-list

I am really having trouble thinking. I am trying to code but mostly copy and paste as I am trying to learn. Hear is the code I've put together so far.

```
  function LinkedList() {
    this.head = null;
    this.length++;
  }
  
  function Node(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.next = null;
  }
  
  LinkedList.prototype.add = function(val) {
    let newNode = new Node(val);
    newNode.next = this.head;
    this.head = newNode;
    this.length++;
    return this.head;
  };
  
  LinkedList.prototype.delete = function(val) {
      let current = this.head;
      while (current.value !== val) {
          current = current.next;
      }
      if (current.next) {
          current.value = current.next.val;
          current.next = current.next.next;
      } 
  };
  
  let linkedList = new LinkedList();
  linkedList.add(1);
  linkedList.add(2);
  console.log(linkedList.delete(1))
```

When I console log the last line it says "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

P.S. I don't even know how people "low g" is that even possible?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to mention your health symptoms :)

Comment: There's no `value` variable in your example. Please post the whole error text, all its lines

Comment: `val` !== `value` in your `delete` function.  Also that function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Ok, that was a silly mistake. I changed it and nothing happened!

Comment: Why would I want to return anything if I am deleting it?

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

- The loop condition `current.value !== val` will be true for all nodes because `current.value` is undefined. It should be `current.val`.
- Since the loop condition is always true, eventually `current` will be `null`, and then `current.value` will trigger the error you got. You should actually expect this to happen also when the above error is fixed, because `delete` may be called with a value that is not present in the list, and then also the loop will run until `current` is `null`. You should exit before this happens.
- The logic you have used to delete a node consists of copying the next node's value, and removing the next node from the list. But this will not work when the node to delete is the very last one. In that case your code will run into an error. Moreover, this is a structural problem: there is no next node to delete, so you'll end up with the same number of nodes. You should really stop the search one node *earlier* and then delete the next node.
- `this.length++` in the `LinkedList` constructor makes no sense, since the `this.length` property does not exist yet when `++` is executed. Moreover, there is no node yet in this list, so the length should just be initialised to 0.
- The `delete` method should adjust `this.length` when the deletion is successful.
- Doing a `console.log` of what `delete` returns is useless: `delete` is not returning anything, so you are just going to see `undefined` in the console. It is not clear why and what you wanted to print. You could let the `delete` method return a boolean, so to indicate whether a node was deleted or not (in case it was not found). If the idea was to print the list after the deletion, then you need to do that separately, and first need to provide a method that allows printing a linked list in a nice way, otherwise you'll just get an object representation as output.
- The `add` method should not return the `head` node. This is not very useful, as the caller should not be bothered with `Node` instances. If you want to return anything, then return the linked list itself (`this`). That way you can allow someone to chain `add` methods, like `linkedlist.add(1).add(2)`.
- Not a problem, but the syntax you have used for creating a constructor and prototype functions is old-fashioned. Since ECMAScript2015 we can make use of the so much nicer `class` syntax. So I suggest you use it.

Here is a new version of your code taking all of the above into account:

```js
class Node { // Use class syntax
  constructor(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
    this.length = 0; // There are no nodes yet
  }
  add(val) {
    let newNode = new Node(val);
    newNode.next = this.head;
    this.head = newNode;
    this.length++;
    return this; // Don't return the head
  };
  delete(val) {
    let current = this.head;
    // current could be null, so protect against run time errors
    if (!current) return false; // Indicate that no deletion occurred
    if (current.val === val) {
      this.head = current.next;
      this.length--; // adjust length
      return true; // Indicate success!
    }
    // Your algorithm can never delete the last node, so we use 
    //  a different algorithm, which looks one node ahead
    while (current.next) {
      if (current.next.val == val) {  // Found it
        // Delete it
        current.next = current.next.next;
        this.length--; // adjust length
        return true; // success
      }
      current = current.next;
    }
  }
  // Make the linked list iterable. This helps with printing
  *[Symbol.iterator]() { // Special property name used by iteration
    for (let node = this.head; node; node = node.next) {
      yield node.val;
    }
  }
}

let linkedList = new LinkedList();
linkedList.add(1).add(2).add(3).add(4);
// Print the list by triggering an iteration
console.log(...linkedList); // 4 3 2 1
if (linkedList.delete(2)) console.log("successfully deleted 2");
console.log(...linkedList); // 4 3 1
console.log("this list has", linkedList.length, "items");
```